# Conditionally wrapping <content> insertion points in Polymer

Tags: polymer, web-component

I am trying to make a Polymer element that is a simple box or container with 3 major elements: a header, body, and footer. The header and footer would be optional, but if they are there, I want to put stuff around them.

My question is how to put a wrapper element around a `<content>` insertion point that only appears if the select attribute matches something?

My code is something like this (doesn't work):

```
<polymer-element name="example-card" attributes="">
    <template>
        <paper-shadow z="1">
            <div vertical layout>
                <div class="card card-header" hidden?="{{!$.header}}">
                    <content id="header" select=".header"></content>
                </div>
                <div class="card card-body">
                    <content id="body" select=":not(.footer)"></content>
                </div>
                <div class="card card-footer" hidden?="{{!$.footer}}">
                    <content id="footer" select=".footer"></content>
                </div>
            </div>
        </paper-shadow>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer({});
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Expected use - no footer in this example:

```
<example-card>
    <div class="header">Header...</div>
    <div>Body...</div>
</example-card>
```

I either want to hide the wrapping div if its content is not selected, or put it in a `<template if="...">` to get rid of it from the light DOM altogether. The `hidden?` expressions above aren't working.

I've tried a few different things with no success, including:

```
hidden?="{{!$.footer.getDistributedNodes().length}}"
```

Is there any way to conditionally wrap  insertion points depending if their selection matched? Perhaps I am going about this all wrong. Thanks!

EDIT: thanks to Fuzzical Logic's help, this is what my revised version looks like, which uses lodash for collection filtering to only select header and footer classes of immediate children:

```
<polymer-element name="example-card" attributes="">
    <template>
        <paper-shadow z="1">
            <div vertical layout>
                <template if="{{showheader}}">
                    <div class="card card-header">
                        <content id="header" select=".header"></content>
                    </div>
                </template>
                <div class="card card-body">
                    <content select=":not(.footer)"></content>
                </div>
                <template if="{{showfooter}}">
                    <div class="card card-footer">
                        <content id="footer" select=".footer"></content>
                    </div>
                </template>
            </div>
        </paper-shadow>
    </template>
    <script>
    Polymer({

        domReady: function () {
            // Doesn't work in IE11...
            // this.showheader = this.querySelector(':scope > .header');
            // this.showfooter = this.querySelector(':scope > .footer');

            this.showheader = _.filter(this.children, function(e) { return e.className === "header"; }).length;
            this.showfooter = _.filter(this.children, function(e) { return e.className === "footer"; }).length;
        },
        publish: {
            showheader: {
                value: false,
                reflect: true
            },
            showfooter: {
                value: false,
                reflect: true
            }
        }

    });
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not that the `hidden?` are not working. It's that `$.header` always resolves to the header with the `id === "header"` (i.e. `this.$.header`). This means it will always be truthy. The easiest way to fix this is to set attributes in your `domReady` event that checks the children.

```
Polymer('example-card', {

    ... other element code ...

    domReady: function() {
        this.showheader = this.querySelector('.header');
        this.showfooter = this.querySelector('.footer');
    },
    publish: {
        showheader: {
            value: false,
            reflect: true
        },
        showfooter: {
            value: false,
            reflect: true
        }
    },

    ... other element code ...

});
```

In order to make this work correctly, adjust your element as follows:

```
<div class="card card-header" hidden?="{{!showheader}}">
    <content id="header" select=".header"></content>
</div>
<div class="card card-footer" hidden?="{{!showfooter}}">
    <content id="footer" select=".footer"></content>
</div>
```

**Important Note**

The above `domReady` code is merely an example and not complete and will find any `.header` in the tree starting from the `content`. The correct way to do this would be to check only the `children`.

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful. Obviously by 'not working' I meant that my expression was invalid, not that `hidden?` was broken. I ended up using a `domReady` that only searched on the children.